# Looping in a SQL QUERY from a huge database to do incremental data pull

Tags: sql, oracle, memory

I have a generic question about structuring a query in SQL.

I have a database for which I need to pull data for the last n days which turns out to be huge to fit in memory.

I have a query like

```
 SELECT * FROM DB_A 
  WHERE data >=n days
```

The best way to fit the query into memory is to use a loop, such that I can pull the data say m days at time ( where m << n)

So how can I do that?

I am not getting any idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Oracle 12c or higher, you can directly use pagination by using OFFSET and FETCH as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_A 
  WHERE data >=n days
ORDER BY n
OFFSET m*x rows
fetch next m rows only;
```

here, x is a number of iterations, starting with 0.

Let's say you want 5 rows at a time.

for the first iteration:

```
OFFSET 0 rows
fetch next 5 rows only;
```

for the second iteration:

```
OFFSET 5 rows
fetch next 5 rows only;
```

Continue till the end .....

Comment: Thanks Tejash. However I did not get it. Well what I am trying is to say pull 30 days of data ( which maybe say 10 million rows). What I am trying to do is pull data by 5 days which is say (roughly 1 million rows say, which will make the pull considerably faster than if I pulled at once 30 million and also may fit my memory) so how can offset and fetch work?. I may not know a priori how many rows of data each 5 day chunk will have a priori. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the data volume is too large to be processed as one, loop explicite on the demarcations dates:

```
 SELECT * FROM DB_A 
 WHERE date_column >= DATE_FROM  and date_column < DATE_TO
```

Note that for the performance (i.e. also for the memory consumption) is not only the number of the result rows is relevant, but *the way you process the data*.

Try to avoid a *cursor loop* on large volume data. The prefered way of processing is not the *row by row*, but *set oriented*, i.e.

```
INSERT ....  SELECT .... FROM DB_A WHERE ...
```

You may profit if the source table `DB_A` is *partitioned* on the relevant date column (`date_column` in the query above). The query will select only those partitions with the constrained dates.

You may profit (while using the SQL approach) from [parallel DML](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/types-parallelism.html#GUID-1D5C8D6C-0A0E-4CDB-8B32-16EC3C856ACC) to boost the performance.

**Example**

Suppose the table `DB_A` contains data of 30 days in the column `date_column`and you want to process  the data in *5 day batches*.

You will end with 6 batches as show in the query below.

The query select the *distinct* truncated days from the table in the first place, than calculates the `batch_idx` using `ROW_NUMBER` and division by 5 with `trunc`. Finally the boundary dates per `batch_idx` are calculated.

```
with batch1 as
(select distinct trunc(date_column)  start_date from db_a),
batch2 as (
select start_date,
  trunc((row_number() over (order by start_date)-1) / 5) as batch_idx
from batch1)
select batch_idx, min(START_DATE) START_DATE, max(START_DATE)+1 END_DATE from batch2
group by batch_idx
order by 1
;

 BATCH_IDX START_DATE          END_DATE           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         0 01.05.2020 00:00:00 06.05.2020 00:00:00
         1 06.05.2020 00:00:00 11.05.2020 00:00:00
         2 11.05.2020 00:00:00 16.05.2020 00:00:00
         3 16.05.2020 00:00:00 21.05.2020 00:00:00
         4 21.05.2020 00:00:00 26.05.2020 00:00:00
         5 26.05.2020 00:00:00 31.05.2020 00:00:00
```

This very same query you can use in a cursor LOOP to process tha data as illustrated below.

Note that `START_DATE` is inclusive, but the `END_DATE` is exclusive.

```
BEGIN
 FOR cur in (
 with batch1 as
  (select distinct trunc(date_column)  start_date from db_a),
 batch2 as (
  select start_date,
   trunc((row_number() over (order by start_date)-1) / 5) as batch_idx
  from batch1)
  select batch_idx, min(START_DATE) START_DATE, max(START_DATE)+1 END_DATE from batch2
  group by batch_idx
  order by 1) 
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Processing dates from '||to_char(cur.START_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy') || ' to ' || to_char(cur.END_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy'));
    insert into DB_TARGET(date_column,....) 
    select date_column,.... from DB_A 
    where date_column >= cur.START_DATE and date_column < cur.END_DATE;
    commit;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The loop will be execute six time with the expected date ranges:

```
Processing dates from 01.05.2020 to 06.05.2020
Processing dates from 06.05.2020 to 11.05.2020
Processing dates from 11.05.2020 to 16.05.2020
Processing dates from 16.05.2020 to 21.05.2020
Processing dates from 21.05.2020 to 26.05.2020
Processing dates from 26.05.2020 to 31.05.2020
```

Comment: Thanks Marmite. Well regarding your first suggestion, that is my question exactly, how to loop??? Say if I am pulling for 30 days of data, then assuming 5 days of data will me managable, how do I use. SELECT * from dB_a where date_col > current date -30 and date_col  < current date -25 and then use a loop till current date ( there will be 5 loops)  and combine all the data from 5 loops to generate one data table.

Comment: @Stan I added example making the approach more explicite.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marmite. This is awesome. I will apply this to my DB and let you know how it went.